# Redirecting all requests from a subdirectory to a specific file

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I wanted to redirect all requests from a specific subdirectory (/portfolio/*) to a specific file in the root of my website (portfolio.php). This way I want to be able to create project-specific pages within the same file as where the overview is being created.

I tried the following, but it didn't work since it stopped images from loading (images were located in the /images/portfolio/* directory), and it also disables my custom ErrorDocument...

```
RewriteRule /portfolio/(.*) /$1 [PT]
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /portfolio.php [L]
```

Anyone has an idea on how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try getting rid of the first rule and adding the pattern to your last rule:

```
RewriteRule ^portfolio.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^portfolio/(.+)$ /portfolio.php [L]
```

And for good measure, make sure multiviews is turned off:

```
Options -Multiviews
```